# How do I 'stack' marginnotes that are triggered on the same line?

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

I'm trying out a new definition style for my thesis. If a new term is introduced, I repeat it in the margin (and emphasize it inline). A simplified demonstration:

```
\newcommand*{\idef}[1]{%
  \marginnote{\fbox{#1}}%
  \emph{#1}%
}
```

Sometimes, two new terms will be introduced on the same line. Right now the second margin-note will just overlap the first. I'd like it placed next to the first. Or below the first, in the absence of horizontal space.

How could I accomplish this?

**Edit:** All solutions proposed so far (including my own) can only place excess notes *below* others. Ideally, when there's space, I'd like a same-line-origin note to be placed *next to* the previous (to its right).

This is tricky, depending on when `\marginpar`s are typeset, exactly. I believe the only way would be to postpone typesetting the note until the end of the line has been reached, and 'prepare it' until then. But I'm a bit out of my element there.

Comment: Use `\marginpar`.

Comment: `\marginpar` often gives me bad placement (right margin on even page for example). I've had more predictable and robust results with `\marginnote`.

Comment: Use also the `mparhack` package. With `\marginnote` you don't have the feature you'd like. Are those margin notes to appear also in the final version? I hope not.

Comment: you could try the (not really finished) `mpnote` package http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78193/margin-notes-with-a-pointing-arrow-that-are-automatically-vertically-adjusted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That looks interesting, but I don't think I need it. My particular margin-notes will rarely use more than one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've decided to go with `\marginpar`. I had issues with that command but I've been able to fix them.

Initially I could not use `\marginpar` because it had bad *placement* and *alignment*, so I found `marginnote` and stuck with it for a while.

**Placement:** I have a specific case where, at the top of a verso page, a note is put in the right (not left) margin. The `mparhack` package didn't work. The `marginfix` package put the note on the previous page, rather than the correct margin. Then I discovered the `memoir` command `\strictpagecheck`, which fixed the issue for me.

**Alignment:** `\marginpar` would align *away* from the main text, rather than *towards* the main text. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32179/14886) fixed that issue for me.

(The `todonotes` package knut suggested is basically `\marginpar` but with a lot of extra formatting. Formatting I don't need, as it happens.)

Comment: As always, I'd rather not accept my own answer if someone else can top it. Particularly, if you can make the margin notes stack horizontally (given sufficient space, otherwise let them wrap to a new line), the green tick is yours!

Comment: The problem with `\marginpar` has always been that it doesn’t work in floats and footnotes. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You may try the [`todonotes`-package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes) for your purposes.

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand{\idef}[2][]{%
  \todo[color=none, linecolor=none,#1]{#2}%
  \emph{#2}%
}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\idef{term} and \idef{another term}
\blindtext

\listoftodos[Terms]
\end{document}
```

The example defines a `todo` without a line from the location in the text to the marginnote. Please refer the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) for other possibilities to format the todonote.

My example contains also a list of all terms.

The result (the red block is not part of the pdf, it is an insertion to show the locations of the inline-idef):

[image: Example output]

Comment: Hm. I recognize the placement of `todonotes`. It's like `\marginpar`, which, for some reason, often gets placement incorrect for me (wrong margin, wrong spacing). `\marginnote` always works, though (apart from the issue I mentioned). <>---<> It also has some rather extreme formatting that I'd have to get rid of and it uses too much space between notes. I'll experiment with this, but it feels like there should be an easier way.

Comment: Perhaps it look now a bit better - I modified the example a bit. And yes, there is some space between the notes.

Comment: Gotta say, kudos for the effort you put into your example. :-) I'll try and play with the `todonotes` options, see if it can work for me.

Comment: You made no MWE, but wrote about 'thesis'. Please refer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33423/todonotes-produces-double-inline-notes-instead-of-single-margin-note-with-class if you use  classicthesis.

Comment: I'm using `memoir`. I just discovered it has some margin-features itself. Checking them out now.